# Nonlinear total least squares / Deming regression in R

Tags: r, pca, least-squares, deming-regression, total-least-squares

I've been using `nls()` to fit a custom model to my data, but I don't like how the model is fitting and I would like to use an approach that minimizes residuals in both x and y axes.

I've done a lot of searching, and have found solutions for fitting **linear** models:

- via the [`deming` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deming/index.html),
- various stackoverflow posts:

  - [total-least-square-method-using-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889809/),
  - [how-to-calculate-total-least-squares-in-r-orthogonal-regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872928/),
- and this very nice CrossValidated post: [How to perform orthogonal regression (total least squares) via PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-perform-orthogonal-regression-total-least-squares-via-pca).
- I've also found a MATLAB solution: [Total least squares curve fit problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110772/total-least-squares-curve-fit-problem),

but these fit a second order polynomial and not a custom, user-defined model.

What I would like is something similar to `nls()` that does the x and y residual minimization.  This would allow me to enter my custom model.  Is anyone aware of any solution in R?

Here's an example, but please note that I'm seeking suggestions on a general solution for nonlinear total least squares regression, and not something specific to this dataset (this is just an example data from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815745/modifying-a-curve-to-prevent-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estim/21819042#21819042)):

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), y = c(1.0385, 
1.0195, 1.0176, 1.01, 1.009, 1.0079, 1.0068, 1.0099, 1.0038)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

(nlsfit <- nls(y ~ a^b^x, data = df, start = c(a=0.9, b=0.6)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method="nls", formula = y ~ a^b^x, se=F, start = list(a=0.9, b=0.6))
```

Does anyone have any suggestion for how I might proceed?

Comment: If you are only looking for R code, that would be off-topic here. However, I can see a more general (NLS + TLS) question here, whose answer can be illustrated in R. You may want to reframe your Q.

Comment: Thanks gung, do you have suggestions on how i should reframe?  I'm not just looking for R code, i'm looking for examples that show how this might be done.  thanks.

Comment: No problem, you're fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a technique called "Orthogonal Distance Regression" that does this.  An implementation in R was recently released:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/introducing-orthogonal-nonlinear-least-squares-regression-in-r/

Comment: Thanks Brian Borchers, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Since links can go dead, can you excerpt the key information here?

Comment: The link points to a blog posting describing a recent implementation of Orthogonal Distance Regression in R.  A google (or google scholar) search for "Orthogonal Distance Regression" will lead you to lots of papers on the topic.